# Angular2 i18n pipe transform in .ts file

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe, angular-i18n

I want to translate messages in my angular2 material snackbars. Problem is to show snackbar I need to pass message as parameter. To translate using i18n: https://angular.io/api/common/I18nSelectPipe . I can't use interpolation as parameter. So how I can transform my message in snackbar?

```
<button md-button (click)="openSnackBar(message, action)">Show snack-bar</button>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/H6rrayAUhBuCx3JOuDCF?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it explicity by calling `tranform` method on new instance of pipe:

```typescript
import { I18nSelectPipe } from '@angular/common';

const msg = new I18nSelectPipe().transform(message, this.inviteMap);
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/zZFJPdOEe23neNfci8JD?p=preview)**

Comment: Ok, I tried to modify your example and create Injectable for Pipe https://plnkr.co/edit/qlcX8g4YX1IKSuktYfRc?p=preview It works good for DatePipe but I have problem with i18nSelectPipe. Can you explain me what's wrong?

Comment: You didn't provide services https://plnkr.co/edit/hWmmZt3ZpUD8tz92Ufqg?p=preview Can you show me example with DatePipe?

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot! :)